# Do I have to register all RequestClient explicitly?

Tags: c#, .net-5, masstransit, webapi

I want to use [MassTransit Mediator](https://masstransit-project.com/usage/mediator.html) in my .NET WebApi project.
I have read the documentation but it is not entirely clear to me. Well, do I understand correctly that each controller method requires a separate `RequestClient`?

```cs
private readonly IRequestClient<IGetPotionsRequest> _potionsRequestClient;
private readonly IRequestClient<IGetPotionByIdRequest> _potionByIdRequestClient;
```

And in configuration:

```cs
x.AddRequestClient<IGetPotionsRequest>();
x.AddRequestClient<IGetPotionByIdRequest>();
```

This way, by creating a new `RequestClient` for each query and using it as a dependency in the constructor, a lot of code will be propagated. Is there any nice and clean solution to this?
And I also have a question about how to handle a case in which I do not return anything in a method, e.g. `HttpDelete` returns `NoContent` and how to do it using Consumer so as not to return anything from it?

Thank you very much for all the answers and examples.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow! I've edited your post to include a link to the third party package you are using and edited the code snippets to allow for [syntax highlighting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting). It makes it easier to read the code if you are familiar with the language.

Comment: Sure, thank you so much for the edits and in future questions I will be applying the corrections you have made here to make the questions better to understand. Thank you for welcoming :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Mediator, `IMediator` also implements `IClientFactory`, which can be used to create a request client in your controller. So instead of depending upon a specific `IRequestClient<T>`, you can have a single dependency on `IMediator` and call `CreateRequestClient<T>`.

Since you are using Mediator, the consumer's `Consume` method completes before the `GetResponse<T>` call returns. You would, however, need to have a response type returned by the consumer. If there is no response type, you could just `Send` the message, and the consumer would still execute before the `Send` call completes (you await calls to *Send* or *Publish*).

Comment: Please correct me if I don't understand well. I can trigger a query like this: `await _mediator.CreateRequestClient<IPotionToDelete>()
                .GetResponse<IDeletePotion>(new {Id = id});` and in Consume method do it like this: `await context.Send(new {});` in which IDeletePotion is an empty interface.

Comment: you'd need to use `context.RespondAsync<IDeletePosition>(new {})` but yes.

Comment: Last question, can I use such a call? `await _mediator.Send<IDeletePotionRequest>(new {Id = id});` and i Consumer simply call my repository to delete some object and not returning anything?

Comment: Yes, that would work, and the _Task_ returned from _Send_ would complete once the consumer has completed.

Comment: Great, thank You very much for Your help and a very good explanation.